# Iterate over Json object in react

Tags: reactjs

Am working on a page development in react,which needs to iterate over json object and display it in a table with select option. Also the json object is dynamic,changes based on the user id.
My json structure is as below.

```
{

    "Employee": {
        "Name": "Emp A",
        "Personal Info": {
            "Age": "25",
            "Sex": "Male"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with object.map function,but unable to fetch the nested object and also not with dynamic json.Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far? Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response,got involved in another assignment. Your code actually helps me to proceed further.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as object.map() in JavaScript. There is `Array.map()`, but it is typically [used on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

To interate through objects, you may use the following:

1) ***Object.keys()***

2) ***Object.values()***

3) ***Object.entries()***

4) and last but not least, the good old ***for..in*** statement

```js
const obj = {
  "Employee": {
    "Name": "Emp A",
    "Personal Info": {
      "Age": "25",
      "Sex": "Male"
    }
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(obj));

console.log(Object.keys(obj));

console.log(Object.entries(obj));

for (const i in obj) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no static `Array.map()` method either, it's `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yep, as mentioned within the link I have posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object.keys

```js
const data = {
  "Employee": {
    "Name": "Emp A",
    "Personal Info": {
      "Age": "25",
      "Sex": "Male"
    }
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

Comment: `Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])`